How to make Swagger only include fields and ignore getters
Swagger is based on Jackson. My Jackson ObjectMapper is configured to not use any getters during serialization, so only the fields defined in the class appear in the serialized object.
However, Swagger seems to always use fields and getters to create the Schema and ignore the visbility setting for property accessors.
Is this a bug or am I missing something? I know about JsonIgnore but this is no option as I can't change the code of the base class, which has methods that start with get but no actual fields.
public class ClassWithAdditionalGetters {

    private String onlyThis;

    public String methodNotStartingWithGet() {
        return "this should not appear in the OpenAPI definition";
    }

    public String getNotThis() {
        return "this should not appear in the OpenAPI definition";
    }

    public String getOnlyThis() {
        return onlyThis;
    }

    public void setOnlyThis(String onlyThis) {
        this.onlyThis = onlyThis;
    }
}

"ClassWithAdditionalGetters": {
        "properties": {
          "onlyThis": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "notThis": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }

